# Get inner function name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wrapper

I have a code like this

```js
function hello(name) {
  return `hello ${name}!`;
}

function wrap(fn) {
  try {
    console.log(fn.name); // cannot get this
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
   } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
   }
}

const wrapper = wrap(() => hello('world'));
console.log(wrapper);
```

Is it possible to get inner function name (hello) from wrap function?

Comment: No, it's not. You get a single function but you can't examine the contents of it. You can look at *the code* you call `toString` but you won't necessarily get the name of any function it calls. For example, it might call multiple function or might call them by something other than their name `a = function b() {}` is a new function with name `b` that can only be called via `a()`.

Comment: By the way, why do you want to do this? It sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but I might be wrong.

Comment: The function you're _passing in_ is anonymous. It doesn't have a name which is why it doesn't log to the console.

Comment: Technically, you can get it from `fn.toString()`, but there are better ways, e.g. using an object with methods `const funcs = { hello(name){` … `} };`, then pass the name of the function as a string: `wrap("hello", "world");` (with e.g. `const wrap = (firstArg, secondArg) => {` … `};`). Call `funcs[firstArg](secondArg)`, get its name by `firstArg`.

Comment: That is a very conceptual question. Your wrap function should be independent and should know nothing about the parameter which is going to be passed. If you feel that you need to know it. Merge these into one function

Comment: I need to create some wrapper function that do custom error logging and the requirement is to have function name logged

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest you push back against the requirement. It's *possible* but you have to fiddle with the prototype of functions and/or `eval`. The result would be *bad* logging that potentially leaves side-effects and might introduce subtle and hard to diagnose bugs.

Comment: I think I will try first with `toString()`, not best but suitable for the requirement 
`const fxName = fx.toString().replace('() =>', '').trim().split('(')[0];`